# How do I set the text of an Android TextView from Java?

Tags: java, android, textview, charsequence

I am currently working on an Android application where I am changing the text in a TextView object while my app is running, from within the MainActivity class. To do this, I am using the `setText(CharSequence text)` method. This method's documentation on the Android Studio website explicitly states that the purpose of the method "Sets the string value of the TextView." However, whenever I try to pass a referenced string from my Strings.xml file as a parameter for this method, I get a NullPointerException with the message "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference." Can somebody please guide me as to why this error is occurring and how use the `setText(CharSequence text)` method with a referenced String as a parameter? Thank you so much!

Comment: add your mainActivity code.

Comment: First you need to initialize your textView , second if you ask a question you need to show what you have done

Comment: Post your code so we can make changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you initialize your textview?

Comment: Can't you put your code here? Is setting a text on `TextView` is that much confidential?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to initialize textview

```
TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
tvName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.name_xml));
```

Also make sure in your setContentView xml the tv_name is declared as TextView in the layout.

Comment: Thanks forgot the coding block

Comment: Hey without knowing where OP went wrong how-come you post an answer ? and can you explain which avoids his null pointer from your answer?

Comment: @Mike, Please add a resource full body to make sure OP can understand what went wrong with his code. Make sure to add a brief body to your answer.

Comment: Simple he is attempting to parse the String on xml as he stated but it is failing, and it is pointing to a parsing an int of a null object reference

Answer (score -1):

another way to do this

```
TextView textview  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);//get the view of textview

//set the text for textview
textview.setText("text you want to set");
```